# order of expansion between variable expansion and command substitution

Tags: bash

The bash man says that variable expansion occurs before command substitution. I was seeking of an example that shows it clearly. So i tried this:

```
root@antec:/# var=1 
root@antec:/# echo $(var=2; echo $var)
2
root@antec:/#
```

I was expecting bash to do:
1) replace $var by "1" in the substitution
2) execute echo $(var=2; echo 1)

Obviously this is not what bash is doing ..
Can someone please explain what is going one here ? And if someone has an example showing the precedence of variable expansion over command substitution it would be nice too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what the bash man page is talking about.

The [POSIX specification for the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06) says:

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> 1. Tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion
>    shall be performed, beginning to end.
> 2. Field splitting shall be performed on the
>    portions of the fields generated by step 1, unless IFS is null.
> 3. Pathname expansion shall be performed,
>    unless set -f is in effect.
> 4. Quote removal shall always be performed last.

This makes it pretty clear that variable expansion (aka. "parameter expansion") happens at the same time as command expansion ("command substitution"), not before or after.

So I do not think the example you are asking for exists.

Comment: In the POSIX quote, what does the "beginning to end." means then ?

Comment: I assume it means "left to right", although there again I cannot think of an example where it would matter.

Comment: Here's a left-to-right example: `a=1; echo $a $((a++)) $a` prints "1 1 2" because the second `$a` is expanded after `$((a++))`

Comment: nice ! Gordon, do you confirm too that there is no examples showing that variable expansion occurs before command substitution ?

Answer (score 0):

What is happening:

a) The $() expression is executed
b) Variables in `var=2` are substituted
c) `var=2` is executed
d) Variables in `echo $var` are substituted
e) `echo 2` is executed

I think a good example of variable expansion first is:

```
foo=echo; echo $($foo)
```

Comment: I don't see how your example is showing that bash perfoms variable expansion before command substitution. Once $foo has been expanded in the subshell, the subshell executes "echo", which return an empty line. Then the main shell performs the command substitution and executes echo "". There is no race between command substitution and variable exansion.

Answer (score 0):

In newer [bash man pages](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/doc/bash.0#L1525-L1528), they put semicolons to indicate the precedence:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion ; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion) ; word splitting ; and pathname expansion.

And from the code you can see that a `$` triggers the [`param_expand`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/subst.c#L10315-L10329) function, which will do [command substitution](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/subst.c#L9795-L9796) or [variable expansion](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/subst.c#L9892-L9893) if the next character is a parenthesis or a name respectively. It will not do an additional variable expansion in `command_substitute`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion here is that you think the variable expansion happens inside a command substitution, when it doesn't.

Actually, bash will only do a command substitution there, where the command is `var=2; echo $var`. That will then be run in a subshell, which will execute the command, doing all expansion passes yet again for each command run.